# WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0: Enabling XACML mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to follow the documentation [Enabling Role-Based Access Control Using XACML](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Enabling+Role-Based+Access+Control+Using+XACML) for WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0.
But adding the features described failed, 
complaining: the XACML feature 5.0.7 cannot be installed since 5.2.0 is already installed (although not visible under "installed features"). Adding XACML Mediation fails due to missing dependencies.

Anyone got this working and can share some insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the features in the new p2 repository has conflicts with existing ones. Basically, it's a bug. I reported this [here in WSO2 APIM JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-5473).

As a workaround, if you only need role based authorization, you can use [oAuth2 scope based authorization](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/12/article-role-based-access-control-for-apis-exposed-via-wso2-api-manager-using-oauth-2.0-scopes/).